# What's the best way to create shared libraries with circular dependencies?

Tags: linux, linker, shared-libraries

Is there a good way to create two libraries, liba.so and libb.so, which depend on each other?  The following won't work unless both libraries already exist:

```
g++ -fPIC -L. -shared -lb a.cpp -o liba.so
g++ -fPIC -L. -shared -la b.cpp -o libb.so
```

I could create liba.so with no dependencies, then create libb.so depending on liba.so, then relink liba.so or fix it with patchelf.  Is there a better way?

Or would it be better for all libraries to have no dependencies, and just make sure the main application links everything that's recursively needed?

Background: This is a bundled application and users will only use the main application, not the libraries themselves.  We are currently using static libraries but are investigating shared libraries to avoid lengthy link times for incremental builds, and to decrease the total size of several applications all using a common set of library functions.

Comment: If your libraries depend on each other then they should be one library. There's no reason to have two if you always have to load both.

Comment: The problem is, if they were one library it would probably be something like 10GB, which we would not want to re-link for each incremental build.  Also, we have many products, each using a subset of the libraries.  Though there are circular dependencies, it is not the case that all 100 libraries depend on all others.

Answer (score 1):

Dependencies aren't necessarily bad but they can sometimes be messy when circular, leading to thing like this in "dumb" linkers that only extract undefined symbols from libraries when they're encountered on the command line.

```sh
-llib1 -llib2 -llib1 # or, progressively worse:
-llib1 -llib2 -llib3 -llib1 -llib2 -llib1
```

I usually just refactor the libraries so that dependencies are one way. For example, split `lib1` so the dependency chain is one way (not *always* possible, but that would be a pretty complex chain):

```
lib1a (depends on) lib2 (depends on) lib1b
```

Comment: Does this needing to list libraries twice also apply to shared libraries?  I thought it was only for static libraries.

Answer (score 0):

It works if you link them thrice, the first time a library without the dependency, then the second and third time linking to each other.

For the first step, you can create the library as a dummy one, with `cc -shared -o libname.so -xc /dev/null`.

Example with two libraries `A.so` and `B.so` which call into each other and two example programs which use each of them:

```
$ cat A.c
#include <stdio.h>
extern void B(int); void A(int n){ printf("%s\n", __func__); if(n--) B(n); }

$ cat B.c
#include <stdio.h>
extern void A(int); void B(int n){ printf("%s\n", __func__); if(n--) A(n); }

$ cat mainA.c
extern void A(int); int main(void){ A(3); }

$ cat mainB.c
extern void B(int); int main(void){ B(3); }

$ cc A.c -shared -o A.so      # or cc -shared -o A.so -xc /dev/null
$ cc -Wl,-rpath=. B.c A.so -shared -o B.so
$ cc -Wl,-rpath=. A.c B.so -shared -o A.so

$ ldd A.so
   ...
        B.so => ./B.so (0x00007fd1149d0000)
$ ldd B.so
   ...
        A.so => ./A.so (0x00007f6504c50000)

$ cc -Wl,-rpath=. mainA.c A.so -o mainA
$ cc -Wl,-rpath=. mainB.c B.so -o mainB

$ ./mainA
A
B
A
B
$ ./mainB
B
A
B
A
```

It would've worked just as well with e.g. `-L. -lA -shared -o libB.so`, adapting the silly example is left as an exercise to the reader ;-)

Comment: Yes, but I was wondering if there was a more direct way.  I suppose I could also have an empty library named libB.so, in a tmp directory, that I link into libA in the first step, to avoid having to generate libA twice.

Comment: This is the directest most obvious way. No, you can't have an empty library -- the linker will not accept an empty file as an object argument. And even if it accepted it, you would still have to create it.

Comment: You can of course first create `libA.so` as a dummy library with `cc -shared -o libA.so -xc /dev/null`, but that would only confuse things up IMHO. I would mention that too, though.

Answer (score 0):

I was hoping there would be an option to `ld` that would allow linking a non-existent library, but I haven't been able to find such.  I've decided the cleanest solution is to use patchelf, which allows adding a dependency without checking existence.

```
g++ -fPIC -L. -shared a.cpp -o liba.so
patchelf liba.so --add-needed libb.so
```